# Admin SDK Auth error, wrong error code

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using the Admin SDK, Auth feature.

When calling `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)` and the token is expired I get the error

> Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh token from your client app and try again. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

With error code

> auth/argument-error

First of all, should the error code not be "auth/user-token-expired"?

Second, the error code I received is not in the [Admin Authentication API Errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors)

I have a hard time handling all firebase errors properly so I can reply with proper error messages to the consumers of my API.

Answer (score 0):

Expired tokens and invalid signatures are [reported](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/token-generator.ts#L227) with the `AuthClientErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT` error code. It seems the value of this constant is defined as `argument-error` in source. This can be fixed in a future release (or alternatively update the documentation to reflect the correct value of the constant, and avoid a potentially breaking change).

There is no such error code as `auth/user-token-expired` in Admin SDK. Suggest you report a feature request in the Github repo if that is important to you.